# Color vision checkup

Tags: c#, object-oriented, inheritance

I have this old project I wrote years ago and it's all classes and methods all over the place. I am trying to learn/understand how I can apply a more OOP principle. It is very large and can't paste all the code here. Instead I will demonstrate what I have as a basic.

Checkup.cs

```
public class CheckUp
{
    //General information
    public string CliniciansName { get; set; }
    public string EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfCheck { get; set; }
    public string CheckUpType { get; set; }

    public ColourVision ColourVisionObject { get; set; }
    ///lots of other checkups like 45 and growing and forever changin
}
```

ColourVision.cs

```
public class ColourVision
{
    public int ColourVisionType { get; set; }
    public int OutcomeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecallDate { get; set; }
    public string Recommendations { get; set; }

    //Contains a few horrible methods to parse form other formats,
    // CSV datatables, XML, but needed. Here is one from a DataTable
    public Boolean ColourVision Load(System.Data.DataTable dt){

        Boolean isLoaded = false;
        System.Data.DataRow row = DataRow;
        try
        {
            ColourVisionType = row["ColourVision"].ToString();
            FFTOutcomeID = Convert.ToInt32(import.getOutcomeValue(row["ColourVisionOutcome"].ToString()));
            RecallDate = (row["ColourVisionRecallDate"] != DBNull.Value) ? (DateTime)row["ColourVisionRecallDate"] : DateTime.MinValue;
            Recommendations = (row["ColourVisionRecommendations"] != DBNull.Value) ? (string)row["ColourVisionRecommendations"] : "";
            isLoaded = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isLoaded = false;
        }
        return isLoaded;

     }


    //And this takes the data row and populates it self
    //by reference from healtchcheck, where there 
    //are thousands of checks and lines of code
    //and this is what I am trying to streamline
    public void Update(ref Data.CheckUp checkUp)
}
```

The database is one table with over 400 columns and contains at least the General Info defined in CheckUp. It may or may not contain 0 more fields up to all the fields.

I am racking up my brain on how to create a Checkup Class, that can load the basic data form the data table, or 0 or more checkup objects, without manually calling methods like this for each kind of import logic.

```
if (ColorurVision.Load(ref dataRowFromSomethingElse) == true ) { CheckUp.ColourVision == null }
```

I am reading about Inheritance and the examples are clear but I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that here. I have a feeling this is perfect project for that. Maybe I am just looking at it wrong. Should I be rather inheriting from something else, like `System.Data.DataTable` and returning `ColourVision`, or `CheckUp`?

This is really a high level code review question based more on programming principles.

Comment: "//Contains horrible methods to parse datatables, XML, but needed." You could also put up these methods for review ;) Wheter in a separate question or as additional code here is up to you. From what you write about your database, I take you have not applied [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This might be worth taking a look at for you. It should make Extraction of Classes for your Data easier.

Comment: Yea OK i put the load from datatable. Its really rough but it has been written and works. I suspect that moving that out o the Model class and into an Extension (Extend DataRow? with 50 extension methods???) would be pretty good OOP? BUt I still have to create lots of lines of codes that call each of these separately and test results.

Comment: I'm troubled by the thought of extending `DataTable` 50 times. Look at @Ocelot20 answer and do some "wishful thinking" about what your classes should look like. Think about what properties should be - for example `Recommendations` - plural - is a single string? I doubt it. DO NOT DESIGN YOUR CLASSES BASED ON THE DATABASE SCHEMA.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest issues I see with this code is naming of Classes/Properties/Methods and proper [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

I find the best way to think about separation of concerns is to think in terms of "has a" relationships to see if they make sense. For example, you might question whether a "Checkup *has an* employment status". When you put it that way, it's pretty clear that a Checkup doesn't make sense to have an employment status, but a *Person* might. It's pretty easy to fall into the trap of saying "I don't need to make a `Person` class because it's not that complex yet". This will come back to bite you later whether it's another developer that can't understand your code (maybe even yourself) or wishing you could more easily modify functionality because the elements are so tightly coupled.

Here's an example of how you might better organize your classes:

```
public class CheckUp
{
    public DateTime AppointmentTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public Clinician Clinician { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }

    // A type of test might be a ColorVisionTest.
    public List<Test> TestsRun { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Clinician : Person
{
    public List<Licenses> Licenses { get; set; }
}

public class Patient : Person
{
    public List<Checkups> Checkups { get; set; }
}

public static class DatatableTestParser
{
    public static List<Test> ParseTests(DataTable dt)
    {
        // Parsing logic here.
    }
}
```

To keep harping on the separation of concerns, let's talk about a comment of yours:

> I am racking up my brain on how to create a Checkup Class, that can
>   load the basic data form the data table

Typically you don't want to have something like a `Checkup` class also be concerned with parsing from things like a datatable. Again, a `Checkup` should only be concerned with being a `Checkup` and nothing more. You could have another class that did parsing from a `DataTable` or other data source, but the key is to separate it from the `Checkup` itself. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: THank you this does make. That is why I am struggling since easc healthcheck contains its properties, plus methods to parse ands save. Its bloating now. So inheritance is really used to define objects and not really for business/data logic (we use INterfaces there?)  THis does make sense and I suppose I can separate it all into tiers that are responsible for it. I suppose there is not much I can do to make reading 400 columns and deciding where to assign them, without writing it out. I thought there might be  a principle that can help deal with that.

Comment: The main purpose of Inheritance is to avoid duplicate code. Whether or not this relates to business logic depends on how you're using it. If you're looking for a way to map properties to an object, there are a ton of tools/patterns to help with that. As it sits however, your question is a bit too broad (hence me commenting on the general OOP aspect of it). You may consider starting a new question that addresses the property mapping aspect of the code specifically.

Answer (score 4):

Just a small observation:

> ```
> public int ColourVisionType { get; set; }
> public int OutcomeID { get; set; }
> ```

From the names of these properties, it looks like your code could benefit from a few `enum` types. An enum value is always easier to read and understand than any magic `int` number:

```
public ColourVisionType ColourVisionType { get; set; }
public OutcomeValue OutcomeId { get; set; }
```

---

This line looks like it's assigning a `string` value to an `int`-typed member - which wouldn't compile:

```
ColourVisionType = row["ColourVision"].ToString();
```

If `ColourVisionType` is what I think it is (if it's not then you have a readability issue!), then I'd try to parse the value into some `ColourVisionType` enum.

I don't see `OutcomeID` being assigned, but I'd give it the same treatment - parse it to a meaningful enum value.

---

Notice I've renamed `OutcomeID` to `OutcomeId` - per the [C# naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), `ID` should be named `Id`.

Comment: Yea.. there are like 400 properties names like this :) I know.. it was years ago but I can work on that I just dont know what the "big picture" is on how to create a proper OOP classes and architecture :(

Comment: I am trying to learn OOP practices and how to apply them. Maybe I am showing the wrong end of the code here, but if I post it it will be 100 pages long... shocking for such a simple thing really. What books you recommend reading?

Comment: Best possible read I can think of would be "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" (the GoF patterns book) - and then "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin, and also "Dependency Injection in .NET", by Mark Seemann.

Comment: I vigorously disagree with starting with the "Gang of Four" book if "I am trying to learn OOP.." Look at some of the "Head First" series like [Object Oriented Analysis and Design](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Object-Oriented-Analysis-Design/dp/0596008678/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1396159467&sr=1-1&keywords=head+first+object-oriented+analysis+and+design)

Answer (score 3):

#### Properties

I like that you use Properties, but I don't like, the Datatype you use:

> ```
> public int ColourVisionType{ get; set;}
> ```

this is definitely **not** an int. You should represent finite element types by enums:

```
public enum ColourVisionType{
     TYPEONE, TYPETWO, TYPETHREE
}
```

Same goes for `OutcomeId`. This is DataStructure. You should not need to care for DataStructure in itself (id, references, etc.) when writing the handling layer

instead reference:

```
 public Outcome Outcome { get; set; }
```

and this also is an enum (As well as `EmploymentStatus` and `CheckUpType`)

```
 public enum Outcome{
     FAILURE, SUCCESS, SOMETHING_DIFFERENT
 }
```

On the other hand, if you had more to an outcome than just a type, you should make it a separate class:

```
 public class Outcome{
      public int OutcomeId { get; set; }
      public Diagnosis Diag { get; set; }
      // [...]
 }
```

#### Talking about data structure:

From what you write about your database, I take you have not applied [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).
This might be worth taking a look at for you. It should make extraction of classes for your data-structures easier.

You might also want to take a look at the [Microsoft Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb386884%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it might help you make your data-fetching easier
[example code]:

```
public boolean Load(int Id){
   try
   {
       using(Context myContext = new Context())
       {
            ColourVisionModel data = (from cv in context.ColourVisions
                                     select cv where cv.id = Id).FirstOrDefault();
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e){
      //handle exception
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks _ most of the top stuff I understand. I will change that as I apply top level changes to everything. I just do not know if I should 50extensions on DataTable? Or Create Base classes and inheritance somehow. PS There are like 10 more methods to load from CSV, from XML, from Webservices, From all sorts. The one file is like a monster, which is OK but its a nightmare to work with. I would like to apply some kind of best OOP practises, speration, inheritance. ANy advice on that?

Comment: @ppumkin in fact I recommend you recreate your whole data layer. DataTable is a hassle to work with, you can instead have EntityFramework do the writing-intensive stuff for you. You need to have a better data-structure first though. I recommend you extract smaller subsets of Columns, that belong together to separate tables. Concerning OOP: Your Data (which is the only thing you posted) does not really care about Object Orientation. You don't have to worry about the OOP Character of your data, just fit them to subsets and it should be fine.

Comment: also you'd need to post code for a better overview. *personally*(!) I **love** using Services. If you combine them with a factory Pattern you can load all sorts of data with always similar calls.

Comment: This project is meant to deal with various people. and guest what, most healthcompanies expoert datat in CSV! YAAAAy :( or Crazy Webservices that embed DataSets! Yaaaay :( And over the years its grown into this monster and I just cannot bear to look at it. There must be a better way, so I am seeking some experienced advice.

Comment: Do you have alink into this factory stuff. I have seen it around but not really understood it. Maybe its worth looking at.

Comment: @ppumkin I found [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/469453/Illustrating-Factory-pattern-with-a-very-basic-exa)